# What is the use of ConvertBack method in IValueConverter interface?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, ivalueconverter

What is the use of `ConvertBack` method in the `IValueConverter` interface.

**When will it be called?**

Or what is the **order of invocation** of the `Convert` and `ConvertBack` methods?

**I have asked the question here because:** I have bound **one property of codebehind** to TEXTBOX’s TEXT Property and am using `convertor` for that property.  The first `Convert` Method invokes and when I change `TEXT` in `TEXTBOX` nothing happens... but as soon as I close the form the `ConvertBack` method invokes.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

IMO, the `ConvertBack` method is used to convert your visual representation of the data to the specific DataType.

For example: you use a Converter to convert a boolean `true` to the string `"TrueBoolean"`. This text will be displayed in your TextBox. When you change the value of the TextBox, the `ConvertBack` method will be called as soon as the binding fires again (default OnFocusLost). Now your `ConvertBack` method will try to convert the new value to the datatype you want it to be. So you will have to implement logic to convert `"FalseBoolean"` to `false`.

```
public class Converter : IValueConverter
{
    object IValueConverter.Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (bool) value ? "TrueBoolean" : "FalseBoolean";
    }

    object IValueConverter.ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var s = (string) value;
        if (s.Equals("TrueBoolean",StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return true;
        if (s.Equals("FalseBoolean", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
            return false;
        throw new Exception(string.Format("Cannot convert, unknown value {0}", value));
    }
}
```

This technique is used a lot in DataGrids if I'm not mistaken.

Hope this is a bit clear...

**UPDATE**
About you question in the comment:
To overwrite the default `OnFocusLost` binding behavior you have to change your binding like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyText, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
<!--syntax might differ, can't access VS at the moment.-->
```

Comment: @Roel, ya but in my case ConvertBack is fire when i closing the window, is n't it a strange?

Comment: no, I think this is normal behavior: Before the window is closed, the OnFocusLost event of the TextBox will be fired, or at least the binding will update.

Comment: @Roel, what should i have to do if i need to have call ConvertBack method as soon as any change make in TEXT of TEXTBOX?  i could n't find update source trigger property as @Dominik says...

Comment: @Roel, How about INotifyPropertyChanged interface? Do you need to implement that on your property in order for the "UpdateSourceTrigger=propertychanged" to work? 

and when is a "Mode=TwoWay" binding relevant? You seem to know your way around this area.

Comment: @MaxMazur yes you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. And `TwoWay` binding is the default for most controls (you can check `BindsTwoWayByDefault ` on the control to confirm). It is relevant for TextBoxes and Checkboxes for example, where it is important that the value can be upated either via code or via user input.

Answer (score 39):

`ConvertBack` is when you have `mode=TwoWay` on your binding.

It converts the user input back into the datatype that you're binding to and gets invoked when the `TextBox` (say) loses focus.

For example (if this wasn't built in), if you have a number that represents a price, the `Convert` method would take the value and format it into a string with the correct currency symbol, decimal separator etc.

If the user types in a new value - including possible currency symbol, thousands separator etc. you'd use the `ConvertBack` method to parse the string and extract the numeric value.

Another example could be credit card number input. The user could enter the number as a single string of digits or groups of digits separated by spaces or dashes. The `ConvertBack` method would take all these possible inputs and convert them to the single format you require.

Answer (score 3):

check the UpdateSourceTrigger Property on your Binding.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

The textbox will by default update the source if it looses focus, using the UpdateSourceTrigger you can set this behaviour to immediate update of the source if the textbox content changes.

HTH
Dominik