# When ConvertBack is called for ItemsControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, itemscontrol, updatesourcetrigger

I have the following item data class, as well as a converter.

```
class ListBoxViewItem
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public Boolean IsChecked { get; set; }
}

[ValueConversion(typeof(List<String>),typeof(List<ListBoxViewItem>))]
class ListToItemConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null) return null;
        IEnumerable<String> l = value as IEnumerable<String>;
        return (from n in l select new ListBoxViewItem() { IsChecked = true, Name = n });
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class ListBoxData
{
    public List<String> AllData
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<string>()
            {
                "FOO",
                "BAR"
            };
        }
        set
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I bind the instance of the `ListBoxData` to a listbox control's `ItemsSource`. As below:

```
    <ListBox>
        <ListBox.ItemsSource>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.Path>AllData</Binding.Path>
                <Binding.Converter>
                    <local:ListToItemConverter />
                </Binding.Converter>
                <Binding.Mode>TwoWay</Binding.Mode>
            </Binding>
        </ListBox.ItemsSource>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Content="{Binding Name}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

So My question is, the `Convert` function is called when the listbox is showing, but as every items in this list box is a checkbox, although I use `TwoWay` binding to bind the instance and listbox, but `ConvertBack` is not called when I check/uncheck the checkbox in this listbox.

I am not sure if `ConvertBack` is designed to work as I expected. But if I want the `ConvertBack` can be triggered when check status is changed, what should I do ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the use of ConvertBack method in IValueConverter interface?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6424074/what-is-the-use-of-convertback-method-in-ivalueconverter-interface)

Comment: No, I know when ConvertBack is called for a textbox control, but in my case, I want to know when ConvertBack is called for one of the item property changed in a itemscontrol.

Answer (score 1):

The ConvertBack method will fire when the Converter is used in a Binding with Mode=TwoWay.
Example is whe it's used in a binding to the Text property of a TextBox.
The "Convert" method will be fired when the value changes when displaying the value in the TextBox, and the "ConvertBack" will fire when the user change the TextBox value.

Answer (score 0):

Add [UpdateSourceTrigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.updatesourcetrigger%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) to Binding and Implement `ConvertBack` function with reverse functionality of `Convert` function.

Change following

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay}">
```

To

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

ConvertBack function is as follows

```
public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
{
    if (value is IEnumerable<ListBoxViewItem>) 
    {
      var l = (IEnumerable<ListBoxViewItem>)value;
      return l.Select(l.IsChecked);
    }

   return null;
}
```

Comment: I tried in a WPF application, and add UpdateSourceTrigger, the break point in ConvertBack never triggered under debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

You are converting `ListBox.ItemsSource`, not `CheckBox.IsChecked`

I don't think `ListBox.ItemsSource` will even work with a `TwoWay` binding since by default ListBoxes do not make changes to their ItemsSource's source collection.

If you want a converter to get run when you change `CheckBox.IsChecked`, then you need to specify the converter to use in the `IsChecked` binding

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, 
                              Converter={StaticResource MyCheckboxConverter}}"
          Content="{Binding Name}"/>
```

But in this case, a converter should not be needed since `IsChecked` is already a boolean value, so you don't need to convert it at all.

If you're trying to trigger something when your `CheckBox.IsChecked` changes, you're better off making sure `IsChecked` triggers a `PropertyChange` notification, and executing code in the `PropertyChanged` event of the class containing the `IsChecked` property.